# Show that the continuum of elements $e^{i\lambda t}$ forms a complete orthonormal subset of $B^2$.

Tags: functional-analysis, orthonormal

> Let $X$ be the vector space of all finite linear combinations of
>   functions of the form $e^{i\lambda t}$ ($-\infty<t<+\infty$), where
>   the parameter $\lambda$ is real. An inner product in $X$ is defined by
>   $$(f,g)=\lim_{T\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{2T}\int_{-T}^T f(t) \bar  g(t) dt.$$ 
>   When $X$ is closed by means of the metric generated by this
>   inner product, we obtain a Hilbert space $B^2$. Show that the
>   continuum of elements $e^{i\lambda t}$ forms a complete orthonormal
>   subset of $B^2$.

This is an exercise by

Young, Robert M. "An Introduction to Non-Harmonic Fourier Series", Revised Edition, 93. Academic Press, 2001.

I do not know how to solve this exercise. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Do you know how to show they are orthonormal?  Completeness is trivial: finite linear combinations are dense in $B^2$ by definition.

Comment: Yes, the scalar product must vanishes. However, for me, this is trivial for discrete case ($e^{int}$ instead of $e^{i\lambda t}$) is not so for the continuous case.

Comment: $\frac{1}{2 T}\int_{-T}^{T}e^{i\lambda_1 t}e^{-i\lambda_2 t}dt = \frac{\sin((\lambda_1-\lambda_2)T)}{2T(\lambda_1-\lambda_2)}$ for real $\lambda_j$ and $\lambda_1 \ne \lambda_2$.